# What dependency do I need to use AmqpAppender for log4j?

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, log4j

In my log4j.properties I have the following line:

```
log4j.appender.queue=org.springframework.amqp.log4j.AmqpAppender
```

In my pom.xml I have the following spring related inclusions:

```
<!-- Spring dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When I startup the application, I see the following exception:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.springframework.amqp.log4j.AmqpAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.amqp.log4j.AmqpAppender  
...
```

What dependency do I require to make use of org.springframework.amqp.log4j.AmqpAppender ?

Comment: set up a lower log level and start your application again, you will see what's going wrong there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correct dependency, but class is different a bit:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender
```

Pay attention to the package, please.

Comment: That means there's an error in the Spring Docs:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/log4j/AmqpAppender.html
Will try that first thing tomorrow monring.

Comment: :-) Good catch! Feel free to raise a JIRA issue on hte matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I think the appender you found is a different one. There is one appender in:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

from [spring-ampq](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/log4j/AmqpAppender.java).

The spring version maybe different too.